# Angular5 get Value of Input on Click

Tags: angular

I have a Form, and I want, if the Checkbox is checked, that the value is submitted with the isChecked function.
But i can't get it working.
I tried it with
`isChecked({{user.username}})` But this is not working.
Any Idea?

```
<form #a="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addGamers(a)">
      <ul class="list-group gamer-list">
            <li class="list-group-item agamer" *ngFor="let user of allUsers$ | async as users; index as i">
                <div class="material-switch">
                    <input id="switch{{user.username}}" value="switch{{user.username}}" name="switchUsername" (click)="isChecked()" type="checkbox"/>
                    <label for="switch{{user.username}}" class="switch{{user.key}}"></label>
                </div>
                {{user.username}} {{ i }}
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you provide the attrs within (), you can access the angular variables directly like

```
<input id="switch{{user.username}}" value="switch{{user.username}}" name="switchUsername" (click)="isChecked(user.username)" type="checkbox"/>
```

and in your component, you can access the function directly:

```
isChecked(userName) { 
   if (userName != null) {
      // your implementation
   }
}
```

if you want to make it onSubmit, then you can use the power of two-way binding in angular2+

in your component:

```
public isChecked: boolean = false;
```

in Html:

```
<input id="switch{{user.username}}" value="switch{{user.username}}" name="switchUsername" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" type="checkbox"/>
```